# Did Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange shift from Jira Service Management to something new?

Tags: support, email, contact

On 07/12/2021 at 3:29 PM IST, I contacted Stack Exchange from https://meta.askubuntu.com/contact.

After contacting, I got an email from community-support@stackoverflow.com like this:

> Hello!
>
> An issue has been created on your behalf in our support portal. You should see a response from us soon with more details or an answer to your question.
>
> ***** – https://support.stackenterprise.co/helpdesk/tickets/*****
>
> Thanks,
> The Stack Overflow Support Team

After couple of minutes, I got another mail from community-support@stackoverflow.com (with this as subject: Activate Your Stack Overflow Support User Account) like this:

> Hi ,
>
> Stack Overflow has a shiny new system that we're using to help serve you better and track all your conversations with us.  As part of it, we have an online portal where you can view and track all these conversations.
>
> We've automatically created a new account for you on it, and you can activate your account and select a password by clicking the link here:
>
> https://support.stackenterprise.co/register/*******************
>
> If the above URL does not work try copying and pasting it into your browser. If you continue to have problems, please contact us.
>
> You can also track the status of any open requests by clicking the link in the footer of the response you receive.
>
> Thanks!
> The Stack Overflow Team

So it would be nice if a staff member can let us know more about the *shiny new system*. Also, if you can, please let us know the reason for shifting from Jira.

---

On a different note, please remove the extra space after "Hi".

Comment: Looks like they're using [FreshDesk](https://freshdesk.com/) now.

Comment: @Smitop IIRC, they were initially using FreshDesk and shifted to Jira. Now they are back to FreshDesk..

Comment: As for empty space, that's where your name should appear, most likely. Do you have the "Real name" field in your profile empty by any chance? If so, that's not a bug.

Comment: Exactly how difficult would it have been to set it up as a subdomain of stackoverflow.com or stackexchange.com, or anything I could recognize instantly as belonging to stackoverflow? Right now, I'd have to waste a few minutes confirming that this is not phishing, because it reads exactly like a well-designed phishing email.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 Are you talking about "Full name"? https://i.stack.imgur.com/qckl4.png

Comment: Well, I contacted them last Sunday, but they were on the old system, when did this happen - if it's even been rolled out across the whole network at all?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I have added details in the post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, we have shifted back to Freshdesk. After spending a long while with Jira and implementing tons of custom functionality through user scripts to make the experience less {let your imagination go wild here}, we decided that Jira just isn't a good option to host support for us.

Because it was still set up from previous use, we migrated directly into the stackenterprise instance for a quicker setup experience. Product Support migrated at the beginning of October and Community Support followed at the beginning of November.

**Note:** Because of the excellent way Jira handles support desks, all tickets that *started* in Jira forever remain in Jira (they send all outgoing responses from their own mail servers instead of using our email address). Replying to an old ticket will send it back into Jira again and not start a new ticket in Freshdesk.

Comment: I sense a *burning* love to Jira here. :-D

Comment: I recall Catija talking about how bad Jira was: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58861506#58861506

Comment: Can you let us know why did SE shift from FreshDeshk to Jira in the past?

Comment: @RandomPerson Was just a consolidation move so that every team was located in one place, and Jira offered a "service" project (essentially a help desk) so everyone figured might as well migrate that too. We're carving out support explicitly from that consolidation, because every team agreed that the help desk option of Jira was subpar. So now every team can either use Jira or Freshdesk if they need a help desk, while the remainder of our operations will stay in Jira.

Comment: BTW, is SO/SE responsible for the UI of https://support.stackenterprise.co?

Comment: @RandomPerson Somewhat. We can customize it, a lot more than other support software allows, but are still limited to a general layout.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Can you please address the issue of extra space after "Hi" in the email?

Comment: @RandomPerson It is as others mentioned in the comments. It's supposed to include your first name there. But the way tickets come in via the contact form, Freshdesk doesn't receive any name when creating those users. If you emailed us directly, the profile would be created with whatever name you sent along in the header of the email.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 If you have used Jira, you'd get the hate. :D