# Make https://support.stackenterprise.co/ mobile-friendly

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-support, mobile-device

The UI of https://support.stackenterprise.co/ is terrible in smartphone to be honest.

There is a lot of empty space on both the sides.

[image]

Please make the UI mobile-friendly.

Also, it is not obvious to a new user what these icons represent.

[image]

<sub>I closed my ticket accidentally by clicking on one of these icons ‍♂️</sub>

Comment: That is an external service (Freshdesk, IIRC) so there is nothing SE can do. Let's not collect feature requests here for services that are only used by Stack Exchange and not owned by Stack Exchnage. You already know this btw: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372717/158100

Comment: @rene Read this comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1244602

Comment: I can look into this next week but can't make promises that it'd be perfect for mobile. Freshdesk is *supposed* to automatically make mobile-friendly versions but maybe we changed something that broke it.

Comment: Thank you for the assurance that you will look into this! @animuson

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the culprit here appears to be this one line:

```
width: calc(100% - 164px);
```

That was being applied to the `page` class, which is the big piece that contains everything. I don't know if that was a part of Freshdesk's default styling or if it was added in at some point, but it doesn't seem to have been doing anything but forcing 82px of padding on either side of the box. Which is weird given the class already has a `padding: 24px` on it and doesn't need implicit padding from its width.

I removed it to see what would happen, and having testing on many different pages I saw no difference whatsoever other than fixing the view for smaller devices. I'll just remain baffled at why it was added in the first place.

Comment: As a bonus, I even spent some time making updates to the ticket details page to not look quite so broken. Unfortunately there's not anything I can do about those buttons.