# Italics is not working in https://support.stackenterprise.co

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-support

Italics is not working in https://support.stackenterprise.co when I am replying to a ticket.

[image]

Please fix this issue.

Comment: Strange. This seems to neither be the standard post editor nor the [new Stacks editor](/q/360033/289905), but some third editor.

Comment: You should not use this site, no idea how you even got access there.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron You are mistaken. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372711

Comment: Well, still, not sure it's considered part of SE network. But let SE staff decide. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron This might be helpful for you to understand the context: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372849 SE staff do accept posts regarding https://support.stackenterprise.co/.

Comment: Huh, so they added yet another burden on themselves. Excellent. As if they don't have enough bugs to fix on the actual sites, they now have another full system with its own codebase and tons of bugs to take care of. </sarcasm>

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron Nah, we actually have zero control over the functionality of this system. We can only make CSS changes and move things around on the page basically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be fixed now. It was applying italics behind the scenes - the style for making it actually appear that way just got overwritten.

Comment: I can confirm that this has been fixed. Thanks for the quick fix.