# Is the old help desk still used?

Tags: support, contact

Continuation of what has been asked/answered here: [Did Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange shift from Jira Service Management to something new?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372711)

Has SE staff completely switched over to the new site (Freshdesk) now? If yes, what happens to any pending/open tickets on the old site? Does staff still look at them?

Assuming the old site is still used:
There is a link to '*Submit a request or report a problem*' (this is disabled in Freshdesk). Does SE normally look at issues reported using this link? Or the ones reported using the Contact form take precedence over the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it is no longer monitored and hasn't been for several months. The old Jira portal should not be used to submit support requests or reply to old requests.

**Update:** We have disabled the ability to manually submit tickets to the Public Q&A board from the portal. This was done for Product Support's board but for whatever reason never happened for Public Q&A.

Comment: For the old tickets that are still open, do you recommend reporting them again using the Contact form, with a link to the old ticket (for background)?

Comment: I wouldn't link to an old ticket in Jira. I would just copy the entire context with maybe a note that you are resubmitting it. Not all staff will have immediate access to the old support desk since they are no longer monitored. You can also email directly to community-support@stackoverflow.com if the contact form isn't viable.